# PhpStorm Show/Hide Main Menu

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I mistakenly hide PhpStorm's main menu using "View > Appearance" unchecked the menu.

I tried many searches on how to show me the main menu again, after long I found a very simple way to do it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Press `Double Shift` for Search Everywhere.

Now search for any setting or anything you want to change.

For main menu show/hide `Press Double Shift` > `Actions` Search for  `View | Appearance main Menu` Then simply `enable` the setting.

This might also work for Jetbrains, Intellij, Pycharm, Clion, or any JetBrains product.

Comment: not working for me. I cannot click the enable/disable for this specific item. The on/off switch simply does not react to clicks.
Other items in the same list do work.