# Missing associated label in Angular material mat-form-field - WebStorm

Tags: angular, angular-material, webstorm, code-inspection

Let's say I have an HTML file:

```html
<form mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="addressForm">
  <div class="u-flex fields-wrapper">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
      <input type="text" matInput formControlName="name" />
    </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="submitName()">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

And I'm on WebStorm developing Angular, I will always get this warning: **Missing associated label**

[image: Missing associated label]

Comment: HINT: If you want to answer your own question then do it properly: put answer as an answer and not as part of the original question. Thanks.

Comment: tnx I have added a question Heading, but I don't understand why downVoted... isn't it solving the question I mentioned?

Comment: 1) I have no idea who downvoted you 2) Your answer indeed solves your question in WebStorm. My comment was: everything that you see above is a **Question**. The **Answer** has to be **completely separate** (see below). Here is an example of a self answered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425945/phpstorm-show-hide-main-menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Angular Material uses `mat-label` instead of `label`. WebStorm inspection relates to it as a warning.

As a workaround, in WebStorm you can go to `Preferences | Inspections | HTML | Accessibility` -> `Missing associated label` and uncheck it.

[image: webstorm inspection settings]
**Note:**
When you are unchecking this checkbox, you will not get a warning also when you are working on inputs that are not `mat-input` and don't have an associated `label`.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow [WEB-43748](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43748) for updates.

As a workaround, you can suppress the **Missing associated label** inspection for the tag by adding `<!--suppress HtmlFormInputWithoutLabel -->` above it. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.3/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-in-editor